# whats the wrongs with this for loop in jquery?

Tags: jquery, for-loop, radio-button

i have a group of 5 elements like radio buttons and i want to set checked attr to each of them with a delay.

```
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide5">
```

and this script added on header:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      for(var i=1; i<6; i++){
          $('input[name=slider]:nth-child(i)').attr('checked', ').delay(500);
      }
   })
</script>
```

but none of not selected. whats my wrong in for loop?

Comment: Apart from the missing quote you mean?

Comment: Use .each  $('input[name=slider]').each(function(){//your code here})

Comment: @user2063626 not needed here

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Okies.. :-)

Comment: hmm...pupose of `delay()`? Actually its little bit confusing....`:)`

Comment: the person who down votes should give explanations rather than just down vote

Comment: @Swarnajith I believe that was the OP

Comment: 'twas me. All the downvoted answers are incorrect or incomplete.

Comment: @Jai im rookie in javascript and added the .delay() just for add a delay to get next loop, i need each radio button show in checked state for a while, but i don't know whats the good way to do it. :D

Comment: @Juhana I don't downvote incomplete answers as long as they're helpful (unless the question is especially unworthy of an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you are after:

[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/vSFtM/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      for(var i=1; i<6; i++){
          $('input[name=slider]:nth-child('+i+')').delay(i*500).show(function() { $(this).prop('checked', true)});
      }
   })
```

**EXPLANATION**

When you run this loop, each element is given a delay to show.  The delay->show runs immediately for each of the elements.  For that reason, you need to continually increase the delay in order to make it appear that they are synchronously tied together.  The first delay is at 500ms, second at 1s, third at 1.5s, etc.  The function in the `show` call is a callback that tells the checkbox to add the property checked=true.

Based on your comments to @Juhana: I would say this would be your best bet (or a slight modification of it):

http://jsfiddle.net/vSFtM/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() { nextIteration(); }, 500);
    var current_index = 1;
    var total = 5;
    function nextIteration() {
      $('#slide'+current_index).prop('checked', true);
      current_index = current_index + 1 > total ? 1 : current_index + 1;
   }
})
```

Comment: Also what Juhana said in the comment.

Comment: It still won't work as intended. `.delay()` at the end doesn't do what the OP thinks it does.

Comment: i did it but just the fifth element checked and loop not work correctly to check others

Comment: tnx thats work, but i dont know why when i run it in my page the radio buttons are doubling?

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` is used only by the jQuery animation queue and it doesn't actually pause the script execution. The original code checked each radio button in turn (instantly) and paused their animation queues (which is empty) for 0.5 seconds.

Here's one that works for any number of radio buttons and doesn't have overhead from `.delay()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=slider]').each(function (index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout( function() {
            $this.prop('checked', true);
        }, 500 * index );
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kmJkP/

Comment: @Juhana thanks man thats work great.
and a another little question, how that loop can become a infinity loop?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. It loops through every radio button regardless of how many there are.

Comment: apologies me for bad english. i have 5 radiobuttons and i want check them with delay in a infinity loop, like a slider.